# Azure Service Bus - Renew message lock automatically when using ServiceBusReceiver

Tags: .net-core, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

Having spent long hours trying to find documentation and help around this resulting in nothing, I have decided to reach out to the community.

I would like to read messages from a topic subscription. Using the message, a UI is populated for a human to work on it. The time it approximately takes to process each message is 15 minutes and each client can work on only one message. At the end of processing the message, the client can either decide to stop processing messages or request a new message.

With the max lock time set at 5 minutes on the subscription, I need to be able to automatically renew my lock for up to 15 minutes.

The first attempted approach was to  use `CreateReceiver` and fetch the message, read it and `Complete` message when done. The issue with this is I have not been able to figure out how to automatically renew the lock for 15 minutes. I see the `RenewLockAsync` function but would like for this to be automatic and not have to run a background timer to keep track of the expiring lock.

The second attempted approach was to try using `ServiceBusClient.CreateProcessor()` with options to set the `AutoLockRenewal` timespan. The issue faced here is with the processor itself running based on events in the background. Since I need to populated a UI, I need to be able to stop the processor after the message has been read, return the callback and once the human interaction is done, complete the message. I have been unable to find a way to do this.

What would be a good approach to achieve this? The subscription acts as a workqueue that multiple people pull items from and individually work them. Any help in a proposing an approach to this is appreciated.